# android.app.Presentation does not work using Fragments

Tags: android, presentation

I am implementing a second-screen integration using android.app.Presentation.
(second-screen meaning e.g. a separate display connected via HDMI)

All the setup etc works fine and I can display simple layouts with views on my second screen.

However now I want to reuse some components I use from within my Activities,
which are Fragments or DialogFragments.

But when I use the LayoutInflater available within the presentation, I crash with
`Didn't find class "android.view.fragment" on path` and when I "steal" the LayoutInflater
from the Activity, I can inflate the layout, but screen size and resolution is that of the 1st (main) screen of course.
Any Ideas how to do this?

Similarly, I have no access to a FragmentManager, and stealing the one from the Activity doesn't rather work. So I would have to recreate/duplicate my reusable component code and layouts redundantly flattened into a presentation layout. Doesn't sound too good to me.

I found the cwac presentation framework; but I don't fully understand what it does (yet) (aka what I understand what it does, does not solve my problem) and it crashes on my Android 7.1.1 anyway (bug opened) so please do not just point me there.

Cheers & kind regards,
Tom.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: sorry no. a lot of copy paste to explode all components into a flat activity.

Comment: also since the lifecycle of the presentation is tied to it's activity, lots of unnecessary in/out animinations just to display the same thing...